# Automatically defining C/C++ include path on WSL Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When using the C/C++ extension for Visual Studio Code with WSL, it will never refer to `/usr/include/` unless you create a project file any time, as you have to allow it to create a local config file called `c_cpp_properties.json`. This means you simply cannot run standalone C files unless you create a workspace around it.

Is there some way to automate this, even a little? It's very annoying having to redefine my standard includes every time I reopen the program.

Ideally I would like to set this up such that I can just work with my C files standalone rather than as a project as I am frequently using university assets and it's very annoying to have to create a project to work with any demo they give me. I have looked everywhere but just can't find any kind of global setting where I can tell the extension to refer to `/usr/include/` - with or without a local config file for the project.

Thanks

Comment: It should refer to /usr/include. Will you show your C/C++ settings.json?

Comment: My settings.json is blank - what should i put in it to set this up?

Comment: Please note that Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code are two very different products.  By the way, since you are using Windows, try Visual Studio, since it is a better tool for C/C++ than VS Code (at least it was 3-5 years ago when I used it).

Comment: I'm only using VS Code because I need the integration to WSL for university coursework - I massively prefer normal visual studio though, thanks anyway.